# Auto populate id depend upon lookup field using class

Tags: apex, soql, class

i need to auto populate the field depends upon lookup field,i have shared an image -hope you will understand.
[image]

I have written class for that-it is not updating(not throwing any error also)
how to achieve this-only in class

```
public class Autopopulatenewassetit 
{
    public ClaimImport__c claimimport {get;set;}
    public Patent__c newpatent{get;set;}
    public Autopopulatenewassetit()
    {
        claimimport = new ClaimImport__c();
    }

    public void Assignid()
    {
        newpatent = [SELECT Id,Asset__c FROM Patent__c WHERE Asset__c != ''];
         claimimport.Assetid_c= newpatent.Id;
         Update claimimport;    
    }
}
```

Comment: In your picture, your `Patent__c` records all point to unique `Asset` records, but is that always the case? If you have a `Patent__c` 'x4' that also points to `Asset` y1, have you considered what should happen? The mere possibility of that happening would change the correct answer for this question.

Answer (score -1):

please try this and let me know if it works!

```
public class Autopopulatenewassetit 
{
public  ClaimImport__c claimimport {get;set;} 

public Patent__c newpatent{get;set;}


public void Assignid()

{

list<Patent__c> newpatent = [SELECT Id,(Select Assetid__c from ClaimImports__r),Asset__c FROM Patent__c WHERE Asset__c = 'DesireValue'];

//claimimport.AssetId__c= newpatent.Id;

list<ClaimImport__c>  claimimport= [select id,Assetid__C from ClaimImport__c  ];
    System.debug(claimimport[0].Assetid__C);//original Value

    for(Patent__c p:newpatent)
    {
         for(ClaimImport__c c:claimimport)
         {
              c.AssetId__c=p.id;
         }
    }
     Update claimimport; 
      System.debug(claimimport[0].Assetid__C);//updated value
} }
```

Comment: it is throwing relationship error

Comment: Did you made AssetId__c as lookup field? if No then do it.

Comment: lookup only,eventhough its throwing error

Comment: i hope i understood exactly what you Need? if no can you suggest where i gone wrong because it's working fine on my org!

Comment: Code dumps are not good answers. As we've seen here, when they don't work, it starts a string of back-and-forth comments to try to get things to work. If you don't add explanation to your answer (_what_ was the problem with the original approach, _how_ can you work around it, _why_ does this answer work? etc...) OP (**O**riginal **P**oster of the question) is not likely to know what needs to change to make your answer work. For those reasons, I have downvoted this answer.

Comment: Hi Dereck, thank you for your perspective! i'll take care of this from next time.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code. In this code, I have created a map of asset(key) and parent record id(value). First get your original records(parent__c records) in a list. Create a map with id as asset__c and value as parent record id. This iterate over loop and put the values one by one as shown in code snippet.

```
 public class Autopopulatenewassetit 
  {
    public ClaimImport__c claimimport {get;set;}
    public List<Patent__c> newpatent{get;set;}
// Key = Asset__c id , value = Parent__c id (Assuming both are of type id)
   Map<id,id> assetMap = new Map<id,id>();
   public Autopopulatenewassetit()
   {
      newpatent = new List<Patent__c>();
      // Here you are creating a new record. You have to query your existing claimport record.
      claimimport = new ClaimImport__c();
      // Query claimimport records.
   }

    public void Assignid()
   {
     // List of records
     newpatent = [SELECT Id,Asset__c FROM Patent__c WHERE Asset__c != ''];
     // Iterating records to create map.
      for(Parent__c p : newpatent){
        // Putting values in map.
         assetMap.put(p.Asset__c,p.id);
     }
   //  assetMap contains all the desired values of parent ids for respective asset id. 
     claimimport.Assetid_c= assetMap.get(claimimport.Asset_c);
     Update claimimport;    
   }
}
```

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Loop must iterate over collection: SymphonyIAM__Patent__c at line 16 column 6

Comment: I have edited my code. You have declared "newpatent" as single object and firing SOQL, It might cause exception if there are more than 1 records. Have changed it to List<patent__c>

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Asset_c at line 21 column 56

Comment: its throwing error

Comment: Code dumps are not good answers. As we've seen here, when they don't work, it starts a string of back-and-forth comments to try to get things to work. If you don't add explanation to your answer (_what_ was the problem with the original approach, _how_ can you work around it, _why_ does this answer work? etc...) OP (**O**riginal **P**oster of the question) is not likely to know what needs to change to make your answer work. For those reasons, I have downvoted this answer.

Comment: @DerekF I have explained it in comments what I have added. In this snippet I am just giving a solution, not a exact code snippet. And that's what we should do. I have seen people posting classes and asking us to write the test class. Salesforce Coimbatore, I don't know why you are getting variable does not exist error because no one on stackoverflow have any idea about your data model. Still I am editing my answer so that you can get more idea about approach how to solve this.